# The screen size overwrites the other ones :S

Tags: html, css

Ive been trying to make a change of my category images depending on screen size. But right now only the first screen width size are being used. It seems as though the other ones are being overridden by the first row of code (max-width: 769px). (on this site: http://origami.directory/)

What can I do so it changes 3 times as it should do?

```
    .category-list-item {
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .category-list-item { width: 20%; }
};
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .category-list-item { width: 25%; }
};
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
  .category-list-item { width: 33.33%; }
};
```

If someone could help me fix this I would be super grateful!
/ Martin

Comment: Hm that looks familiar. I wrote that sample CSS for another question. However I don't really understand your question. Can you add a image where we can see what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the extra semi-colon `;` from the end of your queries.

Your queries should be like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .category-list-item { width: 20%; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .category-list-item { width: 25%; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
  .category-list-item { width: 33.33%; }
}
```

2. Your queries are conflicting with each other making the second query obsolete. Specify a range for each like this:

```html
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .category-list-item{width: 33.33%;}
    }

    @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
        .category-list-item { width: 25%; }
    }
    @media (min-width: 769px) {
        .category-list-item { width: 20%; }
    }
```

**I'm not very sure with the `min-width:769px` part so just let me know what exactly are you trying to do and I'll fix that accordingly. The above is just to show you how queries work basically.**

Comment: Thanks! :) could you check this one out as well?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039534/cant-get-get-queried-object-id-to-work-on-a-image-category-based-website

Comment: Please mark this as the right answer if it helped you in fixing your issue Martin. And checking the other question now.

Comment: Hi again. Do you mean you are checking this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039534/cant-get-get-queried-object-id-to-work-on-a-image-category-based-website?

And also. How do I mark this as the right answer? / Martin

Comment: Just click on the tick mark on the left side of the answer Martin. And regarding the other question, I think that is wordpress related so you should post that in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ instead.